# Order by Year and Month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to order by Year and Month from a date olumn which has that has YYYY-MM-DD.

Below is an example of my code:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT CONCAT(YEAR([DATE]), '-', MONTH([DATE])) AS 'YM' FROM randomTable WHERE [DATE] IS NOT NULL
)sub1
GROUP BY sub1.YM
ORDER BY SUB1.YM asc
```

This doesn't quite work but it's close, I am getting

`2017-11
2018-10
2018-11
2018-12
2018-3
2018-4
2018-5
2018-6
2018-8
2018-9
2019-1
2019-10
2019-11
2019-2
2019-3
2019-4
2019-5
2019-6
2019-7
2019-8
2019-9`

The problem is the `2019-10 2019-11` and the `2018-10 2018-11 2018-12`. How can I make this work so it's all sorted correctly?

Comment: Why can't you just order by the date column itself?

Answer (score 0):

How about keeping `[DATE]` and using that for the ordering?

```
SELECT sub1.YM
FROM (SELECT CONCAT(YEAR([DATE]), '-', MONTH([DATE])) AS YM, [DATE]
      FROM randomTable
      WHERE [DATE] IS NOT NULL
     ) sub1
GROUP BY sub1.YM
ORDER BY MIN([DATE]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is caused because YM is text, and alphabetically '2019-10' comes before '2019-2'.

But that's easy to fix.

```
SELECT sub1.YM 
FROM (
    SELECT FORMAT([DATE],'yyyy-MM') AS [YM]
    FROM randomTable 
    WHERE [DATE] IS NOT NULL
) sub1
GROUP BY sub1.YM
ORDER BY sub1.YM asc
```

Then '2019-10' comes after '2019-02'

Btw, this query can be made shorter.

```
SELECT FORMAT([DATE],'yyyy-MM') AS [YM]
FROM randomTable
WHERE [DATE] IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY FORMAT([DATE],'yyyy-MM')
ORDER BY [YM]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you are looking for:

```
     SELECT distinct CAST( YEAR([DATE]) AS varchar)  + '-' + CAST( month([DATE]) AS 
     varchar) AS 'YM', year([DATE])as 'Y',MONTH([DATE]) as 'M'
     FROM randomTable  WHERE [DATE] IS NOT NULL order by Y,M
```